# Is there a way, othen than inline-block, for elements to don't break line?

Tags: html, css

I have elements wrapped into a parent div, and they're all floated to left. The parent element has `overflow: scroll` and when the parent become thinner than the children, i don't want the children to break line, but the parent to overflow them horizontally.

I've discovered that i can do this by using: `display: inline-block` for the children to behave text-like and then, set the parent to `white-space: nowrap`. This way, they will not break.

But i want a solution with the **children floated**. Can someone help me?

**[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/9dg3gh8d/)**

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: scroll;

  /*does the trick*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.child{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 190px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

---

*[edit] - Since Paulie asked in the comments, i've got to say that no, they don't **have to be** floated for working. I know this. But I want to know if there is another way to accomplish that and I think that there is no better place for this but the SO community*

Comment: Why do they **have** to be floated? Since there is a perfectly obvious non-float option that you *know* works...why the requirement for floats?

Comment: Use a `min-width` on the `.parent`

Comment: They don't **have to** but i don't want be a a single-solution-man. IF there is a way to do this with them floated, i want to know. Since i've searched pretty much everywhere and couldn't find, i came to SO to ask the community if **there is a way to[...]**. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @FilipeMerker, well sorry to say but doesn't that mean you are changing your question's original issue? you wanted with float then why accepting flex? sorry to point out but i think its not good for future user.

Comment: Float elements make that elements out of the flow. It's the default and the correct behaviour. It's because of this that `float` should **not** be used for layouts, only for float certain elements. Otherwise, you are forced to make clearfixes by tons

Comment: It's better inline-block. That's for this.

Comment: LEo the lion, i agree. i'll change the question.

Comment: try giving the `.parent:{display:table;table-layout:fixed;}` and `.child:{display:table-cell}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox can do that and it doesn't even need the `white-space:nowrap`.

```
.parent {
  padding: 3px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto; /* or scroll */
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  height: 190px;
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 10px;
```

}

```css
.parent {
  padding: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  height: 90px;
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9dg3gh8d/5/)

Answer (score 2):

`display: table` does do that too, though `flex` is a more appropriate way to do layout than `table`, unless you need it to work on for example IE8/9, which `flex` doesn't, but then again, your `inline-block` is more appropriate than `table`

```css
.parent{
  padding: 3px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: table;  
}
.child{
  display: table-cell;  
  height: 190px;
  min-width: 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```